# How to refactor ruby code?

Tags: ruby, refactoring

Hi i have a code i would like to refactor

```
def gear_type
  @gear_type ||= self.class.gear_types.find{|gears| gears["id"]==source["gear_type_id"]}["text"] if source["gear_type_id"]
end

def brand
  @brand ||= self.class.brands.find{|node| node["id"]==source["brand_id"].to_s}["text"] if source['brand_id']
end
```

what is best way? to use eval or define method? i've tried this but there are some error i can't discover yet:

```
%w(gear_type brand).each do |meth|
  define_method(meth){
    instance_variable_get("@#{meth}") rescue
      instance_variable_set("@#{meth}", self.class.send(meth.pluralize).find{|node| node["id"]==source["#{meth}_id"]}["text"]) if source["#{meth}_id"]
  }
end
```

Comment: Code review/refactoring is now on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd just write a common finder method that you can parameterize:

```
def gear_type
  @gear_type ||= generic_finder :gear_types, "gear_type_id"
end

def brand
  @brand ||= generic_finder :brands, "brand_id"
end

def generic_finder(collection, primary_key)
  self.class.send(collection).each do |object|
    return object["text"] if object["id"] == source[primary_key]
  end if source[primary_key]
  nil
end
```

Comment: +1 Nice one! Every time we think we need meta programming we should think first if we can do it with a generic method passing symbols. Even the find_by_* method on Rails was changed to this approach.

Answer (score 1):

`instance_variable_get("@#{meth}")` does not raise an error if the instance variable is not set, it returns nil. So you have to do almost the same you were doing:

```
%w(gear_type brand).each do |meth|
  define_method(meth){
    instance_variable_get("@#{meth}") || instance_variable_set("@#{meth}", self.class.send(meth.pluralize).find{|node| node["id"]==source["#{meth}_id"]}["text"]) if source["#{meth}_id"]
  }
end
```

You should also refactor that line. It has to many stuff on it

```
%w(gear_type brand).each do |meth|
  def source(meth)
    @source ||= source["#{meth}_id"]
  end

  def class_meths(meth)
    self.class.send(meth.pluralize)
  end

  def look_for(meth)
    class_meths(meth).find{|node| node["id"] == source(meth)}["text"]
  end

  define_method(meth) do
    value = instance_variable_get("@#{meth}")
    instance_variable_set("@#{meth}", look_for(meth)) if !value && source(meth)
  end
end
```

Here is a try. Not sure if it got better or not, but it's easier to read I think.

Oh! I just realized those methods probably won't be on the scope when the meta? method is called. But oh well, it's still a good example I think :)

Answer (score -1):

It's probably cleaner just to use eval:

```
%w(gear_type brand).each do |meth|
  eval <<-RUBY
    def #{meth}
      @#{meth} ||= self.class.#{meth.plural}.find{|item| item["id"]==source["#{meth}_id"]}["text"] if source["#{meth}_id"]
    end
  RUBY
end
```